# Наследник QSqlTableModel возвращает пустые записи

Tags: sqlite, qt5, model

Имеется класс наследник QSqlTableModel, в котором переопределён только метод data. При этом метод QSqlTableModel::record(int row) возвращает пустую запись, поля в которой QVariant(Invalid). При этом названия полей возвращаются верные. База данных - sqlite

Comment: Пока что из вашего описания ничего не понятно. Добавьте ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснил, что метод QSqlTableModel::record() в своем теле несколько раз вызывает метод QSqlTableModel::data(). Поэтому, при переопределение метода QSqlTableModel::data(), отваливается метод QSqlTableModel::record().